# Al agregar banner el RecyclerView no agrega una nueva posicion

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, admob

Al colocar un banner en el recyclerView no genera una nueva posición para ese elemento (banner) si no que "monta" o lo coloca en la posición de los elementos prácticamente eliminando el elemento que se encuentra en esa posición.

Estoy utilizando kotlin pero si la solución esta en java no hay ningún inconveniente, necesito la idea básicamente de como hacerlo, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

OnCreate

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val v: View = when (viewType) {

            TYPE_ADS -> LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_ads, parent, false)
            else -> LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_download, parent, false)
        }

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }
```

getItemViewType

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        return when {
            position % 8 == 0 -> TYPE_ADS
            else -> TYPE_CONTENT
        }
    }
```

ViewHolder

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(item: files) {

            if (itemViewType == TYPE_CONTENT) {

                itemView.type_file.text = item.type
                itemView.img_file.setImageDrawable(item.img_file)
                itemView.name_file.text = item.name_file
                itemView.size_file.text = item.size_file
                itemView.path_file.text = item.path_file

                itemView.path_file.isSelected = true

            } else {

                val ads_view = itemView.layout_ads

                val adview = AdView(context)
                val adSize = AdSize(300, 70)
                adview.adSize = adSize
                adview.adUnitId = idBanner
                (ads_view as RelativeLayout).addView(adview)
                adview.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(idTestDevice).build())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la colaboración.

Comment: En lo que mostras del codigo esta claro que si es de tipo ADS el item sera un Ad y si es de tipo CONTENT sera un card_download. Es por eso que si indicas que un item es ADS se pisa, yo veo 2 soluciones posibles, la primera es agregar un item de tipo ADS en el array que usa para cargar los datos dentro del recycler. Otra solucion seria agregar card_ads dentro de card_download y hacerlo VISIBLE o GONE si es de tipo ads o no. La solucion depende de que se ajuste mejor a tu app, el item debe tener un add o debe ser un add? he ahí el dilema

Comment: tu comentario me dio una idea muchas gracias, respondo mi pregunta agregando la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo mi propia pregunta por si en algún momento alguien necesita una solución a este mismo inconveniente.

Kotlin permite en el data class definir si uno de sus elementos sera nulo

```
data class files(var type: String? = null, var img_file: Drawable? = null, var name_file: String? = null,
             var size_file: String? = null, var path_file: String? = null)
```

A todos les agregue la opción de que si era necesario fueran nulos.

Al momento de agregar los elementos verifico si la posicion donde se va agregar coincide con el itemViewType del adaptador

```
if (listFilesDownload.size % 8 == 0 && listFilesDownload.size != 0) {

    listFilesDownload.add(files(null, null, null, null))
    listFilesDownload.add(files(obtenerType(f), obtenerIcono(f), f.name, obtenerPeso(pesoF), f.path))

} else {
    listFilesDownload.add(files(obtenerType(f), obtenerIcono(f), f.name, obtenerPeso(pesoF), f.path))  }
```

También agregue en el if la condición que si esta en la posición 0 agregue un elemento normal (entra en el else), si se cumple la condición primero agregara un elemento con todas sus variables nulas para generar la posición donde se colocara el banner (TYPE_ADS) y después agregara el elemento.